# How to preserve position in Flutter SliverList?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to implement SliverList in Flutter to preserve its current position before loading new data so a user can continue scrolling from preserved position?
We are adding data to the begining of the list by swipe down.
Items have'nt the same height.

We want exact behavior as Twitter's timeline list.

Bellow is the code

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white24,      
  drawer: SellTellDrawer(),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    key: const PageStorageKey(0),
    controller: _listScrollController,
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.4),
        
        title: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return SellTellTitle(
            onPressed: () {
              //_key.currentState!.();
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            userLogged: signInController.logged,
          );
        }),
        
        floating: true,
        
        expandedHeight: 50,
        pinned: false,
        snap: false,
      ),          
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          ...hometimelineController.data.map((timeline) {
            final sellTellWidget =
                _sellTellBuilder.buildSellTellWidget(timeline);
            return RowHeaderSellTellWrapper(
                name: "Durdja Djuric",
                email: "@djurdjadjuric",
                sellTell: sellTellWidget);
          }).toList()
        ]),
      )
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: MainBottomNavigationBar(
    controller: _scrollController!,
    userLogged: signInController.logged,
  ),
  floatingActionButton: signInController.logged
      ? FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            routerController.showAddSellTell = true;
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        )
      : null,
);
```

}
}

Comment: Did you try setting a PageStorageKey for the CustomScrollView? Something like 'key: const PageStorageKey(0)' could do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but without success. Just to mention. CustomScrollView contains SliverAppBar and SliverList. It also has ScrollController so it can trigger loading data when user get to the top of the SliverList.

Comment: Ah I see!Are you using SliverChildListDelegate or SliverChildBuilderDelegate?

Comment: I use SliverChildBuilderDelegate. I could copy code if it would help.

Comment: Try the SliverChildListDelegate delegate instead and that should make it work. Code samples always help!

Comment: I've just added code. I've tried with SliverChildListDelegate but I don't see any change.